Access nested formArray in html in angular 14
I have one formGroup name addDocument in it there one fromarray name scholarshipArray and I have added six formGroup inside it , and each formGroup have one formArray name examDetail and inside it there is four controls. My task is to generate six form dynamic so I have add six formGroup inside scholarshipArray and I have generated six form using scholarshipArray, now i have to also use examDetail formArray to generate some control inside those six form  i have to achive like this. I have made the six form dynamic but notable to access the examDetail in html
the form 
created six FormGroup inside scholarshipArray
added control to each examDetail in each formGroup
created six form
but notable access examDetail
getting error

Please edit the question to include code excerpts and error-messages as text-blocks delimited by triple-back-ticks.
